# filter on multiple properties with single search key using Array.filter()

Tags: javascript, angular

```js
let data = [
  {
    moduleName: "Module 1"
    videoTitle: "Add or invite manufacturers"
    videoURL: "source1.com"
  },
  {
    moduleName: "Add User"
    videoTitle: "Add or invite users"
    videoURL: "source2.com"
  }
]
```

if my search term is "add", this search should apply to "moduleName and videoTitle"

```js
let result = data.filter((s) => { 
    s.videoTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
});
```

I am able to apply only 1 property with this syntax, how can apply search on 2 properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can test on multiple properties in the filter method.

```js
let data = [{
    moduleName: "Module 1",
    videoTitle: "Add or invite manufacturers",
    videoURL: "source1.com",
  },
  {
    moduleName: "Add User",
    videoTitle: "Add or invite users",
    videoURL: "source2.com",
  }
];

const searchKey = 'Add';

let result = data.filter((s) => s.videoTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) !== -1 && s.moduleName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) !== -1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another condition

```
let result = data.filter((s) => { 
   s.videoTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) !== -1 && 
   s.moduleName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase());
});
```

To simplify, you can make use of `includes`:

```
let result = data.filter((s) => { 
   s.videoTitle.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey) && s.moduleName.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey);
});
```